Subtle image shifting in Chromium
When comparing large images, e.g. formatted long texts, by switching between Chromia tabs, I often need a subtle vertical shift: When I click on the vertical scroll arrow, the image always moves by many pixels and I can't set the matching parts in the same position, as I need and as I have achieved it for short texts. Can someone advise me how to move such an image more gently, preferably by individual rows of pixels? Thanks!
